# Unable To Add Scroll Bars To A Canvas Widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Using Python 2.7.16 on a iMac.
New to Python and this forum.
I have an application that has a canvas widget which the user can drawn on and I want to add scroll bars to it. I have been trying for the past two days and been having no luck. I have looked at numerous example but I can't get anything to work.

How can I do that?

Below is a screen shot and strip down source code to the essential code.
In the screen shot the scroll bars on the outer window. I want the scroll bars on the drawing canvas which is the black area.

Thanks.

[This what my code example produce.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OG6k.png)

This what my code example produce.

[This is what I want with the canvas having scroll bars.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGdYz.png)

[Now it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9LdJ.png)

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    
    import Tkinter as tk
    
    WINDOW_SIZE='950x650'
    
    
      ##########
      # Size for canvas draring area
      ##########
    
    MAX_X = 600
    MAX_Y = 600
    
    
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Cluster")
    window.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)
    
    # Create a frame parent for the canvas and scrollbar(s).
    p_frame = tk.Frame(window)
    p_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.NW) 
    
    
    Canvas_frame = tk.Frame()
    Canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="black", height = MAX_Y, width = MAX_X)
    
    Canvas.pack();

    coord = 10, 50, 240, 210
    arc = Canvas.create_arc(coord, start=0, extent=150, fill="red")
    
    line = Canvas.create_line(0, 0, 20, 20,  300, 300, 400, 400, fill="dark violet")
    
    lbl = tk.Label(window, width=15, height=5, borderwidth=2, relief="groove", anchor="center", justify="center", text="fasfdasf") 
    lbl.pack()

    
    # Create a vertical scrollbar linked to the canvas.
    vsbar = tk.Scrollbar(p_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=Canvas.yview)
    vsbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)
    Canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsbar.set)
    
    # Create a horizontal scrollbar linked to the canvas.
    hsbar = tk.Scrollbar(p_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=Canvas.xview)
    hsbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
    Canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=hsbar.set)
    
    
    # Start Tk's event loop
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see where you've tried to add a scrollbar.

Comment: I update the code segment in my original post and  added a screen shot of what it produces. A little tiny thing with scroll bars that don't scroll.

Comment: Your code won't run as posted. There are issues with the indentation. Also, your comment says there is a frame for the canvas and scrollbars, but clearly the canvas is not being added to the frame since the canvas is created before the frame.

Comment: The lack indentation was the way the web site adjusted it. I move the creation of the parent frame before the creation of the canvas not the scroll is in the upper left corner of the window and separate from the frame. see add image.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if "the website adjusted it" or not. The only thing we have to go by is what you post. It's your responsibility to post an accurate representation of your code. This code still won't run because you're trying to use `pack` on the canvas but you're using `grid` on the frame, and they are both in the root window.

Comment: Sorry but it does run and I included a screen shot of it. It's just not the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should not put the scrollbars inside the canvas. Typically the canvas and the scrollbars should share a common parent.

If you want the scrollbars to appears as if they are inside the canvas, create a frame with a border and the put the canvas and scrollbars inside the frame.

Comment: I added a parent frame, see edit to code in original post, and now the main window/application doesn't show and the program just hangs. Now I'm really confused.